# How do I unlock bootloader when OEM unlock setting is missing in Developer options?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, bootloader

I have a HTC 816G Dual SIM. As you can see in the image below of Developer options there is no "OEM unlock" option. What can I do to unlock bootloader?

[image]

Comment: The "Allow OEM unlock" option is not standardized. Every manufacturer can implement an own mechanism. Therefore just use your favorite search engine and search for "htc 816g bootloader unlock". You will get some pages that show you how to unlock your device.

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.x don't have this option, this option was first seen in lollipop (5.0).

[This I've found on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/desire-816/help) if you don't find a guide to unlock your bootloader ask in the help thread.